# Google maps react have HeatMap?

Tags: google-maps, reactjs

I need to make a heat map using react and google maps.but I am not finding in the maps react documentation. Do not heat google map for react? Could someone help me ?. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This part of the docs explains how to add a heatmap layer in javascript (which should be relevent for use within react)

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap

```
new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
          data: points, //the 'heat' of the heatmap
          map: map //the map instance
        });
```